# Which is the most appropriate way to find if a specific software is installed in Windows, using C++?

Tags: c++, windows-7

I'm writing a software that in a given moment needs to find if a given software is already installed (by its name) - so the same thing a installer does when it's going to installad its software and sometimes allerts that that software is already installed in the PC.

The problem is that I don't know which would be a good way of doing this. Now the softwares just looks to the default folder and if its unable to find the .exe, he then asks for the user to point out where he installed the software or else consider it uninstalled.

But I would like it to do things by its own; it should be capable of finding if a software is installed without user inputs, and I'm not sure which would be an efficient way of doing this.

The only way I found now is to do the same thing Windows' Add/Remove Programs does: look at many registry entries and try to found it, but I think this would take too much unacessary time give the fact it would look in many places to find only one software.

So isn't there any other less costful option in C++?

Thanks,

Momergil

Comment: Friendly message: "Checking environment. This may take approximately 2 minutes" will solve your problem, IMO.

Comment: *"software is already installed (by its name)"*... that's the problem, no one detects his own software by *name*! Don't avoid the Windows Installer system; take advantage of it! It will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this point, Mehrdad. Well, I guess that's not that much of a problem; the probability of two people create a software with exact the same exe name is quite low and also of both being there on the guy's computer. So I guess work with the executable name is also fine :)

Comment: Checking the environment seems to be a good solution only if we're talking about software that comes only as an executable in a zip archive. Not exactly what I had in mind, but thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are looking for is a **key path**: a registry location that is uniquely tied to that software.
You have two options:

1. A Registry key that is always present **only** when the software is installed.
   eg. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\BitTorrent\uTorrent
2. Look at the unique Uninstall entry of that software at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` &
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
   You will always find a REG_SZ here titled *DisplayName* which is used as the title in "Add Remove Software" Control Panel extension.

Comment: I think your anwers was the most practical one, and I have already implemented it with success :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This depends entirely on how the thing you want to ask about is installed. If it's always installed from an MSI, you can read up on MSI and learn to call the API and/or read the registry to see if its unique ID is there.

If it's installed with 'unzip', there's no concise solution.

Comment: MSI? Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 2):

[`MsiGetProductInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130.aspx) might get you the information you need, if you used Windows Installer.

If you didn't, well, then there's your problem... it's there for a reason.

Comment: A nice solution, but I would be happier with a more generic solution :)